# PHP variable $user_id code stopped working

Tags: php

I inherited a small office pool site.  Recently my host upgraded my server and the PHP scripts stopped working.  I was able to work through some errors and suppress some others for now, but the $user_id isn't kept after login.  After login, I can see the "players" links. Choosing 1 of the links brings up the page but with no user access. Any new page requested acts as if not logged in. I'm sure the code is very old. I just need to get back up and running to finish the season.  I'm not sure how to do this. Hope it is ok to read.

```
<?  
session_start();

include "functions.php";
include "uiFunctions.php";

// session_register("user_id");
$_session['userid']= $user_id;
// session_register("groupID");
$_session['groupID']= "groupID";

// log in/out sequence
if ($logout) $user_id = 0;
if ($login_step)
{
    $check = dbFetch("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user='".$userName."' AND 
pass=PASSWORD('".$userPass."') AND ((activated>0 AND 
banned=0) OR is_admin=1)");

    if ($check[0])
    {
        $user_id = $check[0];
        $page    = "";
        dbQuery("UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE 
id='".$user_id."'");
    }
}

$user_info  = dbFetch("SELECT full_name, is_admin FROM users WHERE 
id='".$user_id."'");
$user_name  = $user_info[0];
$user_admin = $user_info[1];

$page_path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];


// -----------------------------------------------------------------
$m_curSystemTimeStamp = dbFetch("SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
$m_curSystemTimeStamp = dbFetch("SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT('".$m_curSystemTimeStamp[0]."', '%Y-%m-%d'), ".

"DATE_FORMAT('".$m_curSystemTimeStamp[0]."', '%H:%i:%s')");

$m_CURDATE = $m_curSystemTimeStamp[0];
$m_CURTIME = $m_curSystemTimeStamp[1];
?><html>
<head>
<title>Pick'em</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='base.css' type='text/css'>
</head>

<script language=javaScript>
<!-- 

function finishedLoading()
{
<? if (!empty($user_admin)) echo "return;"; ?>

for(x=0;x<document.all.length;x++)
{
    me = document.all[x];
    tg=me.tagName;
    if (tg=='DIV' || tg=='IMG' || tg=='TD' || tg=='SPAN' || tg=='B' || 
tg=='BODY' || tg=='FONT' || tg=='NOBR')
    {
        me.unselectable='on';
        me.style.cursor='default';
    }
    }
 }

-->
</script>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
style="background: #3A4774 url(img/page_bg.gif) repeat-x" 
onLoad="finishedLoading()">
<table align=center border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td rowspan=3 width =1><img src="img/spacer.gif" height=123 width=1>
</td>
 <td          height=1><img src="img/spacer.gif" width =770 height=1></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="logo_text" height=55>Pick'em</td></tr>
<tr><td class="logo_text" height=48><img src="img/spacer.gif" width =770 
height=1></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan=2>
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr><td valign=top width=140><img src='img/spacer.gif' width=140 height=1>
</td>
    <td valign=top width=640><img src='img/spacer.gif' width=460 height=1>
</td>
</tr><tr><td valign=top>
<?
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    // the left panels
    uiStartPannel("Site map", 135);
        uiLink("Home"        , $page_path);
        uiLink("Race results", $page_path."?page=race_rez");
        uiLink("Standings"   , $page_path."?page=standings");
        uiLink("Rules"       , $page_path."?page=rules");
    uiEndPannel();

    uiPannelDelimiter();
    uiStartPannel("Players area", 135);
        if (empty($user_id))
        {
//              uiLink("Log in here" , $page_path."?page=closed");
            uiLink("Log in here" , $page_path."?page=login");
            uiLink("Register now" , $page_path."?page=new_user");
//              uiLink("Register now" , $page_path."?page=closed");
        } else {
            if (empty($user_admin))
            {
                uiLink("Make your picks", $page_path."?page=make_picks");
                uiLink("Everyone's pick", $page_path."?page=everyone_pick");
                uiLink("Player info..." , $page_path."?page=view_player");
                uiLink("Driver info..." , $page_path."?page=view_driver");
            } else {
                uiLink("Everyone's pick"  , $page_path."?
page=everyone_pick");
                uiLink("Edit players"     , $page_path."?page=adm_users");
                uiLink("Edit player picks", $page_path."?page=adm_picks");
                uiLink("Edit races"       , $page_path."?page=adm_races");
                uiLink("Edit race results", $page_path."?page=adm_results");
                uiLink("Edit drivers"     , $page_path."?page=adm_drivers");
            }
            uiLink("Prize Table", $page_path."?page=prizes");
            uiLink("Change password", $page_path."?page=change_pw");
            uiLink("Log out" , $page_path."?logout=1");
        }
    uiEndPannel();

    $serverDate = dbFetch("SELECT DATE_FORMAT('".$m_CURDATE."', '%D %b 
%Y')");
    echo "<div class=pannel_text><br>Server time: <br>".
            "<div align=left>".substr($m_CURTIME, 0, 5)." ".$serverDate[0]."
</div></div><br><br><br>\n";

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    echo "</td><td valign=top align=center>";

    // the middle area
    if (empty($page)) $page = "home";
    include $page.".php";

 ?></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><? PushCopyrightNote(); ?></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Is the global variable for Session case sensitive ? Should in uppercase "$_SESSION" ?

Comment: $_SESSION didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand the code: After log in sequence the user_id is not saved in Session. And this line `$_session['userid']= $user_id;` always set the user id to an not existing variable.

Maybe this works:

```
<?  
session_start();

include "functions.php";
include "uiFunctions.php";

// log in/out sequence
if ($logout) $user_id = 0;
if ($login_step)
{
    $check = dbFetch("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user='".$userName."' AND 
pass=PASSWORD('".$userPass."') AND ((activated>0 AND 
banned=0) OR is_admin=1)");

    if ($check[0])
    {
        $user_id = $check[0];
        $page    = "";
        dbQuery("UPDATE users SET last_login=NOW() WHERE 
id='".$user_id."'");
        $_SESSION['userid']= $user_id; // Write in session
    }
}

// Read from session
$user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];
$user_info  = dbFetch("SELECT full_name, is_admin FROM users WHERE 
id='".$user_id."'");
$user_name  = $user_info[0];
$user_admin = $user_info[1];

$page_path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: This worked.  Thanks. I commented out $_session['userid']= $user_id; and added your lines and now I'm staying logged in.  Of course, now I can't logout.  But I'll plug away at that.  Hopefully I gave you the credit above. If not, I'll fix it.